# Seeking Transit Feed (GTFS) Toolset for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, general-transit-feed-specification, transit, network-analysis

I can see that ArcGIS has a transit feed toolset that enables converting the .txt files from GTFS data directly into usable feature classes for GIS.

I am trying to develop catchment areas in the Greater Metropolitan Area of Montreal accessible within 20, 40 and 60 minutes.

Is there a toolset like the ArcGIS one (see link below) that I can use in QGIS?

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/an-overview-of-the-transit-feed-gtfs-toolset.htm

Answer (score 1):

Using PostGIS, we successfully integrated GTFS data directly into our database and used bus stops to calculate accessibility to students using our existing PGRouting datasets which used street centerlines from the City and County of Denver.

PGRouting gives you the ability to create a routable 'network', from which you can derive drive time polygons, point-to-point routing, etc. etc. from whatever origins and destinations you might have in your database.

GTFS data, for your application, sounds like taking the transit stops and deriving drive time polygons along a network, is that correct?

The ArcGIS tools are aimed at integrating GTFS data into an existing ArcGIS Network Dataset.